# How to use binary keyword in sqlquery which compares values of two colums?

Tags: mysql

Guys I need help with my query. I am using a mysql database and I need to select a value from one table if values of two columns are the same with passed parameters. In this case I am trying to select EmployeeID from table Employee if his UserName and Password match, but it doesn't act like case sensitive. For example if I am trying to select Employee with username 'admin' and I pass the value 'Admin' or 'ADMIN' it gives me back entry with 'admin' as username. I don't want that. It's not case sensitive. I found out this can be done with Binary keyword, but it only works when comparing one column.

I tried this:
SELECT EmployeeID FROM `tblEmployee` WHERE BINARY UserName = 'admin' and Password = 'Something'

And this:
SELECT EmployeeID FROM `tblEmployee` WHERE BINARY UserName = 'admin' and BINARY Password = 'Something'

It shouldn't give me any result because the entry with UserName admin has a password '**something**'. How can I use the BINARY with the second column?

Comment: I hope you are not **really** storing password in clear text.

Comment: no this is just an example

Comment: I sure hope so. That being said, your problem doesn't seem possible. Could you provide the output of `show create table tblEmployee` and give some sample data that doesn't work.